# How to detect when a variable changes value

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, variables

How can I easily detect when a variable changes value? I would like the execution of the program to break on the debugger whenever a specified variable changes value. Right now I'm using Eclipse's debugger.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

For a class or instance variable

1. right-click on the variable in the outline view
2. select "Toggle Watchpoint"
3. Then, in the breapkoints view, you can right-click on the resulting
   entry
4. select "breakpoint properties"
5. deselect "Field Access".

Comment: How to insert a breakpoint when any variable in the program equals a certain value?

Comment: @JudeDesir I'm pretty sure that feature doesn't exist anywhere, it would cause ridiculously bad performance.

Comment: Is there a similar method for local variables within methods?

Comment: I'm not using eclipse these days, but I doubt that it exists. It's easy enough to just put a breakpoint on each line of the method that changes the variable.

Comment: This feature does exist, but enabling it can cause the program to run much more slowly.  Use it sparingly.  It is not always easy to see where a field might be changed, especially when the object containing it is passed to other methods.

Answer (score 23):

OR
Toggle  Breakpoint on the line where the variable is declared, then right-click on the resulting entry, select "breakpoint properties" and deselect "Field Access".

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure about Eclipse, but in IntelliJ IDEA, you can right click on a break point and add the conditions, just like you would in an `if` statement. Then, the debugger only pauses at the break point if its condition is true.

For instance, [in this case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTEpe.png) it only stops if `min == 4`.