# Spy / Watch variable in Android (Eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, variables

I am new to Android development with Eclipse. I am asking a very basic question : 
is it possible to watch / spy the content of a variable during the debugging session? (a bit like in Visual Studio)

I know It is a fairly lame question, but I couldn't figure it out myself.

thanks in advance,

Gallien

Comment: Have you looked at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575336/how-to-detect-when-a-variable-changes-value

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First select **Debug** perspective as:

[image]

Then set **Breakpoints** at places you want:

[image]

After that create a Debug configuration via **Debug As->Debug Configurations...** and then Debug as **Android Application** as shown below:
[image]

Then in Debug perspective you can trace/watch value of your desired variable by pressing **F8**:
[image] 
That's it, you can also evaluate expressions through **Expressions** view. If it is not  enabled select it from: 
**Window->Show View->Other->Debug->Expressions**.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Expressions tab in the debug perspective. Also you can observe the variable when you hit a breakpoint - check this link: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may view variables whilst debugging.

To set a watch point, select a variable in the 'Outline' view in the 'Debug' perspective. Right click the variable, and press 'Toggle Watchpoint'.

More information available [here](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/variables/ref-variables_view.htm)

Answer (score 0):

When you have open debug perspective, click window->show view->expressions. After that, you can input a variable name manually. You can select a variable in code then right click, there will be a link named 'watch'. You'll get it!

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest way, is to hover over the variable name while debugging and it shows you the whole object. I work on eclipse kepler latest version.

[image]