# Eclipse + breakpoints = nothing happens

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to use Breakpoints in Eclipse, but when I set them - nothing happens.
Really.
For example in MVS when the program reachs breakpoint it stopps and I can see variables.

How to use breakpoints in Eclipse in the same way?

Comment: Are you running in debug mode? It doesn't sound like it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to be *debugging* the program, click the little bug next to the run button instead of said run button

Answer (score 2):

First select **Debug** perspective as:

[image]

Then set **Breakpoints** at places you want:

[image]

After that create a Debug configuration via **Debug As->Debug Configurations...** and then Debug as **Android Application** as shown below:
[image]

Then in Debug perspective you can trace/watch value of your desired variable by pressing **F8**:
[image] 
That's it, you can also evaluate expressions through **Expressions** view. If it is not  enabled select it from: 
**Window->Show View->Other->Debug->Expressions**.

Comment: You can use **Java** in place of **Android** as I just copied my own answer for doing this in Android [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531015/spy-watch-variable-in-android-eclipse/10532714#10532714)

Comment: It would have been more appropriate to post a comment linking to the related answer directly instead of copy and pasting the same answer twice.